# How can I set the prometheus.enabled flag to true in VMWare's Kubernetes FluentD Operator using the helm chart?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, prometheus, metrics, fluentd

I currently have a Kubernetes FluentD operator[[1]](https://github.com/vmware/kube-fluentd-operator) running in my environment. It deploys fine using the helm chart but I need to somehow set the `prometheus-enabled` flag when deploying the helm chart.

The documentation states the following :

```
usage: config-reloader [<flags>]

Regenerates Fluentd configs based Kubernetes namespace annotations against templates, reloading
Fluentd if necessary

Flags:
  ...
  --prometheus-enabled          Prometheus metrics enabled (default: false)
```

My question is, can I set this flag when I run the helm chart? ie.

`helm upgrade --install kfo <prometheus-enabled=true> \$CHART_URL --namespace \$INSTALL_NAMESPACE -f kfo/config.yaml`

where `config.yaml` consists of :

```
---
meta:
  key: metadata
  values:
    region: ${AWS_REGION}
    env: ${ENV}
    cluster: ${KUBERNETES_CLUSTER_TYPE}
rbac:
  create: true
image:
  repository: vmware/kube-fluentd-operator
  tag: v1.12.0
fluentd:
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: fluentd-template-mapping
      mountPath: /templates
extraVolumes:
  - name: fluentd-template-mapping
    configMap:
      defaultMode: 420
      name: fluentd-template-mapping
```

If not, what can I do to set it?

Thanks

---

### Links

1. VMWare's fluentd operator - https://github.com/vmware/kube-fluentd-operator

Comment: Just to add, if this flag is not set then the metrics service will not be deployed.
https://github.com/wandera/kube-fluentd-operator/blob/a9335d09e39dc9068a90dba44c6e0508e0a78542/log-router/templates/service.yaml

Comment: FYI available values you can override can be found here: https://github.com/vmware/kube-fluentd-operator/blob/master/charts/log-router/values.yaml

Comment: Thanks, I just read that file and I was able to set the flag in the values file. It was just a simple one liner. `prometheusEnabled=true` and then the service was installed. I'm now getting the metrics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the chart and it appears you just need to add `prometheusEnabled: true` to your `config.yaml`:

```
---
meta:
  key: metadata
  values:
    region: ${AWS_REGION}
    env: ${ENV}
    cluster: ${KUBERNETES_CLUSTER_TYPE}
rbac:
  create: true
image:
  repository: vmware/kube-fluentd-operator
  tag: v1.12.0
fluentd:
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: fluentd-template-mapping
      mountPath: /templates
extraVolumes:
  - name: fluentd-template-mapping
    configMap:
      defaultMode: 420
      name: fluentd-template-mapping
prometheusEnabled: true
```